Invertibility of matrix exponential
I have found several proofs that matrix exponentials are invertible.
However, in Matlab, I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{100}$ that is full rank.
However, rank( expm(A) ) is rank $1$ and therefore, noninvertable. Should this be a numerical precision problem?

It's some kind of problem that's for sure. It's hard to say without knowing what the matrix is.

B = expm(A) returns a Boolean or Boolean array. Try rank(expm(A)) instead.

You can't put (B = expm(A)) into the parentheses like that. You should instead do B = expm(A); and then rank(B).

Even when the dimensions of $A\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ are small $(n\sim10)$, you will have issues if the elements are greater than $A_{ij}\simeq 10.;$ If the dimension are larger $(n\sim 100)$ then you will have issues even for small elemental values. The reason is that the magnitude of the elements of $e^A$ grow very quickly and double-precision floating point loses precision, which drives $\operatorname{cond}(e^A)\to\infty.;$ The quick fix is to use extended precision, i.e. $n=100$ digits.

one exploration:  let $A_1 = e^A$   while $A_2 = e^{-A} .$  Find out approximate sizes for off diagonal elements of $A_1 A_2$   and, now that I think of it, $A_2 A_1$
